# Хранение пароля в открытом виде в сессии

Tags: php

На сайте двухэтапная система авторизации. После прохождения первого этапа логин и пароль записываются в сессию в открытом виде. 6е чувство мне подсказывает, что это очень плохо. Но не могу понять почему. Также в сессию записывается timestamp. И если он больше 180 секунд - сессия чистится и редиректит на первый этап.  Время жизни сессии 0. Плох ли данный способ? Если да то почему и как можно это исправить? Спасибо!

Comment: Если HTTPS нету, то пароль узнают все, через кого идёт интернет, а если ещё и вайфай открытый, то пароль узнают вообще все в радиусе сотни метров от пользователя

Comment: Где можно про это почитать? Или хотя бы что загуглить?

Comment: man in the middle

Comment: а зачем пароль храниться в сессии. для чего он в последствии используется

Comment: Ну по сути если на сайте http, а не https - все равно записывается в сессию пароль или нет. Его можно этими же способами узнать. Т.к. он все равно передается на сервер при проверке хэша. Правильно?

Comment: Он используется для авторизации wordpress

Comment: любопытно. а разве в wordpress надо авторизоваться при каждом обращении, там же то же сессия и все

Comment: короче, то что вы держите в сессии может прочитать практически любой желающий в пределах сервера. но если кто то уже получил доступ к серверу, то все что угодно он и так может узнать смотря все данные после того как их https уже расшифровал. так что я бы сказал, что такое решение на безопасность сильно не влияет. хотя и облегчает сбор паролей кому то на сервере, прочитать сессии быстрее, чем встраивать перехват запросов

Comment: Хотя я наврал немножко. Если под «сессией» имеется в виду PHP-сессия, та которая с PHPSESSID, то тогда по интернету передаётся только этот самый PHPSESSID, а пароль по интернету не передаётся, и всё в принципе безопасно. Тогда прочитать пароль сможет только тот, у кого есть доступ к серверу и к содержимому сессий на нём, как Mike написал

Comment: Тем не менее, зачем вообще хранить пароль в открытом виде? Когда сервер вдруг взломают и прочитают все базы и все сессии, от хранения открытых паролей станет очень грустно.

Answer (score 1):

Пароль нельзя хранить в открытом виде даже в вашей БД.
Используйте токен для авторизации и поддерживания сессии пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Вот видео с примером использования токенов на PHP
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNU1CYryF_8

Answer (score 0):

Не обязательно хранить именно пароль. Проверяйте полученный с POSTa пароль и сверяйте с записью в БД, если "==" - тогда просто записывайте какую-то строку а-ля
$_SESSION['login'] = 1;
А по истечению времени - ансетите переменную.